# Do Jedi take an oath to destroy the Sith?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, sith, revenge-of-the-sith

In the dialog that preceeds the Anakin vs Obi-Wan's fight

> **Anakin:** You turned her against me!
>   **Obi-Wan:** You have done that yourself!
>   **Anakin:** You will not take her from me!
>   **Obi-Wan:** Your anger and your lust for power have already done that. You have allowed this Dark Lord to twist your mind until now... until now you have become the very thing you ***swore to destroy***.

Is this to be taken literally? Is it included in the Jedi code an oath to destroy the Sith, or something like that? Or was it just a matter of speaking?

Comment: We know that the oath also contains a vow of celibacy.

Comment: @Richard - actually, no. They are prohibited attachment, not sex.

Comment: I always took it that he was speaking of the dark side in general, not necessarily the Sith in particular.

Comment: @dvk - Interesting. What is the basis for this assertion?

Comment: @DaveJohnson ... I didn't even take it to mean the Dark Side, but more *evil* in general ... it seems to me this is what Obi-Wan was pointing towards when they confront each other in this scene. I always thought Obi-Wan was telling Anakin he had become evil, which is what he had sworn to destroy with the Jedi Oath.

Comment: There was a scene in Attack of the Clones were Anakin tells Padme he's gonna stop people from dying. That seems to be his goal in life, to end suffering and death. But when he turns to the Dark Side, he tries to kill his wife and murders a bunch of kids. So he's essentially become the very thing he swore to destroy.

Answer (score 8):

This was most likely just a heated (no pun intended) saying.

The code itself does not state to destroy the Sith but to preserve life. Although they do swear to protect peace in the galaxy, thus indirectly swearing to destroy what ever threats posing to disrupt peace.

So what he said was true, from a certain point of view.

Comment: That's pretty much always the answer. "Is what this Jedi said true?"
"From a certain point of view."

Comment: @KSmarts: Jedi were the original politicians.

Comment: Perhaps Anakin told Obi-Wan during their time together that he wanted to destroy the Sith. Maul killing Qui-gon, Dooku's doings and some clone wars stuff (not sure if canon anymore) can support Anikans hate for the sith. Maybe as a kid he said "Obi-Wan, I swear I will destroy the Sith for what they have done!". Then Obi-Wan says: "You must let go of your anger"... or something like that.